# Name Instances of Class Member Template Function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider this code which obviously doesn't work but illustrates what I want to do.

```
struct C {
   template <int I>
   void f(float x) {...}
...
   using one = f<1>;
   using two = f<2>;
};

C c;
c.one(4.0f);
c.two(77.0f);
```

There a 10 member functions for my class that can take 2 value, not type, template parameters and I want to give them distinct names so the user doesn't have to type in the template parameters. This is illustrated by `one` and `two` above.

Any ideas how to do this with C++17, or even C++20?

Update:

Nice answer below but as mentioned a bit verbose. I'm trying to avoid:

```
void one(float v) { 
   f<1>(v); 
   }
```

although my actual statements would be slightly longer.

Hoped something concise was available.

Answer (score 3):

You can't alias member functions directly. But you can write wrappers that forward to them:

```
template<typename... Args>
decltype(auto) one(Args&& ...args) { return f<1>((Args&&)args...); }

template<typename... Args>
decltype(auto) two(Args&& ...args) { return f<2>((Args&&)args...); }
```

[Here it is live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XRA2yzpKrOEAw5RH)

A little verbose to write, but does provide the simplicity you want for the client programmer.

Comment: That is a bit verbose given I'm trying to avoid:


void one(float v) { f<1>(v); }



Thanks for the answer. Let's see if anyone has something more concise.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept to call `one` and `two` with a little different syntax

```
(c.*one)(4.0f);
(c.*two)(77.0f);
```

you can declare `one` and `two` as (constant, if you want) pointers to methods of `C`.

I mean... **outside** `C` you can write

```
using mftype = void(C::*)(float);

constexpr mftype one = &C::f<1>;
constexpr mftype two = &C::f<2>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
 {
   template <int I>
   void f (float x)
    { std::cout << (x+I) << std::endl; }
 };

using mftype = void(C::*)(float);

constexpr mftype one = &C::f<1>;
constexpr mftype two = &C::f<2>;

int main ()
 {
   C c;

   (c.*one)(4.0f);
   (c.*two)(77.0f);
 }
```